# why is electric field inside a conductor zero?

Tags: electrostatics, conductors

I know that the net electric field inside a conductor is zero due to field made by induced charges. But , IS IT NECESSARY ?
what i mean is that what would happen if the net electric field inside a conductor was not zero . ( what would happen if the electrons are not in equilibrium inside a conductor? )

Comment: Four downvotes without any explanation is rather unfair to the op.  They can't fix a problem they don't know about.

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a conductor.

In the normal case, when there is no external field, there is no field inside the conductor, so field is zero.

Let’s talk of the other case. Initially the conductor is in a position like shown below in absence of external field (Blue dots are electrons. Of course, I have not shown all electrons. The idea is that charge is uniformly distributed).

Suppose you switch on an Electric Field, maybe you bring a very large charged metallic sheet.

Now, you might think, ' There’s the field inside conductor'. But you’re forgetting a thing. It’s a conductor. **These charges rearrange themselves with electric field and they move as the electric field affects them**

**It has been proven that there should be no net forces on the objects that make up the system: the charges contained in the conductor.**
Free electrons available always arrange themselves in such a way that conductor is always in minimum potential configuration, in other words arrangement of free electrons ensure equipotential inside the volume of a conductor.
**A perfect conductor is a material that carries unlimited number of free electrons, here free electrons in a conductor are the electrons that are not bound to any particular atom. Thus conductor having huge number of free electrons is a dynamic system that always tries to achieve stable equilibrium or minimum potential energy configuration.**

We know that field is negative gradient of potential. If potential is minimum, field should be zero.

As electric field is switched on, electrons move against electric field and accumulate at one side of metal. Naturally, other side gets positively charged. So, the result is an internal field due to accumulation of charges. The charges in middle stop moving a bit later because the internal field has exact same strength as external field.

Inside the conductor, now there are actually 2 equally balanced opposite Electric Fields. So net field inside conductor is zero.

A  physics professor had nice way of putting it across like this:
“The charges move in a conductor so as to kill the external field.”